# Yii1 Multiple Joins to Same Table

Tags: php, yii

I have the following relation in my Tickets Model:

```
'rl_status_id'=>array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'RelatedFields', '', 'foreignKey' => array('status_id'=>'related_id'),'condition'=>'model = "Tickets" AND field = "status_id"');    
'rl_category_id'=>array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'RelatedFields', '', 'foreignKey' => array('category_id'=>'related_id'),'condition'=>'model = "Tickets" AND field = "category_id"');
```

I am trying to show a Cgridview that has sortable columns for the Category and Status.

I am using the following to join the table:

```
$criteria->with = array('rl_category_id','rl_status_id');
```

I am also using the following CSort:

```
$sort = new CSort();
    $sort->attributes = array(
        Yii::t('app','model.tickets.category_id')=>array(
        'asc'=>'rl_category_id.related_value',
        'desc'=>'rl_category_id.related_value desc',
        ),
        Yii::t('app','model.tickets.status_id')=>array(
        'asc'=>'rl_status_id.related_value',
        'desc'=>'rl_status_id.related_value desc',
        ),
```

When accessing the page I get an error that a field in the `related_fields` table is ambigous, presumably because this is being joined twice effectively.

In the tickets table the status ie numerical however, I wish to sort the column by the text in the related fields table ie `Open` as opposed to the numerical value in the column in tickets.

By only using one in the `Csort` and the `With` the Grid sorting works as expected. But including a second from the same table causes a break.

I have found very little, but I understand you can add an alias to relation and also to the with. Therefore I have tried the following:

```
$criteria->with = array('rl_category_id'=>array('alias'=>'rl_category_id'),'rl_status_id'=>array('alias'=>'rl_status_id'));

'rl_status_id'=>array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'RelatedFields', '', 'foreignKey' => array('status_id'=>'related_id'),'condition'=>'model = "Tickets" AND field = "status_id"','alias'=>'rl_status_id');    
'rl_category_id'=>array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'RelatedFields', '', 'foreignKey' => array('category_id'=>'related_id'),'condition'=>'model = "Tickets" AND field = "category_id"','alias'=>'rl_category_id');
```

But the issue still persist. I have tried with setting one of the above and both together. I can confirm in my condition there is no mention of the issue field and I have removed all other conditions completely to ensure this is not the issue.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to proceed?

**Note**

I have included an answer of my own also as the situation is probably unique to me, but may help some others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use alias for tables to disambiguish (last element of array):

```
'rl_status_id'=>array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'RelatedFields', '', 'foreignKey' => array('status_id'=>'related_id'),'condition'=>'model = "Tickets" AND field = "status_id"', 'alias' => 'rlStatusId');    
'rl_category_id'=>array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'RelatedFields', '', 'foreignKey' => array('category_id'=>'related_id'),'condition'=>'model = "Tickets" AND field = "category_id"', 'alias' => 'rlCategoryId');
```

Check also the documentation:

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/it/database.arr

Comment: Many thanks for your response. I did try the aliasing but this did not work for me. I have found out why this is and have included an answer of my own also. But certainly your answer is the correct way to achieve this. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find the issue and can confirm the aliasing does work as expected. My issue was actually in the relation and not the `criteria` of the `dataprovider`.

When building the relation I needed to change:

```
'rl_category_id'=>array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'RelatedFields', '', 'foreignKey' => array('category_id'=>'related_id'),'condition'=>'model = "Tickets" AND field = "category_id"','alias'=>'rl_category_id');
```

To

```
'rl_category_id'=>array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'RelatedFields', '', 'foreignKey' => array('category_id'=>'related_id'),'condition'=>'rl_category_id.model = "Tickets" AND rl_category_id.field = "category_id"','alias'=>'rl_category_id');
```

The main difference being that I have filed names in the condition of the relation itself, `model` and `field`. By prefixing them in the condition also, this resolved the issue.